# How do you vertically align text in TextFormField with a suffix in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I want my form text to be vertically centered and in line with the suffix since it's annoying me that it isn't.

Inside my `InputDecoration`, I've tried setting `contentPadding` to `EdgeInsets.zero` but that just ended up doing this. [image: actual result] I would love for it to be like the first form field, the only difference would be having the suffix there. Here's the code.

```dart
return Form(
  key: _addSubjectFormKey,
  child: Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
    child: Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[
        TextFormField(
          textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.words,
          autofocus: true,
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            filled: true,
            hintText: 'Enter subject name',
          ),
          textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
        ),
        SizedBox(height: 20.0),
        TextFormField(
          textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.words,
          autofocus: false,
          keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
          textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
          decoration: InputDecoration(
              contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
              filled: true,
              hintText: 'Enter your name',
              suffix: IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.keyboard),
                onPressed: () => {},
              )),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
```

Comment: why do you have set `contentPadding` to `EdgeInsets.zero` in the first place?

Comment: I want my form fields to be the same height. Without `contentPadding` being set to `EdgeInsets.zero`, the field with the suffix gets way taller and I can't match it with the other field's height.

Answer (score -1):

You may try adding `textAlignVertical: TextAlignVertical.center` to your TextFormField:

[image]